# android overridePendingTransition doesn't work when apply theme in activity

Tags: android, android-animation, android-theme

in the very beginning, I didn't define the THEME attribute in manifest.xml,
and I invoked the method `overridePendingTransition(animSet1, animSet2)` immidiately after calling startActiviy, all the animations were valid；

but then I tried to define the style Theme in my main activity (via Theme.Translucent.NoTitle.FullScreen),
What I got is: the enter animation was applyed, while  exit one doesn't work as expected, it remained fullscreen.

I also see the log in LOGCAT as follows:

```
07-16 16:06:46.405: W/khrn_client(12147): init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1 type 1
07-16 16:06:46.405: W/khrn_client(12147): init_window window 0x4da9ed18, 480x800 hintTransform 0x0
```

I consider there's something special when using both theme and activity animation.

who can help me or recommend some documents about this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. If I set `windowIsTranslucent` to  `true` and `windowBackground` set to transparent, the exit animation doesn't work. Did you solve this problem already?